# Como converter um lista sequencial numa ligada em linguagem C

Tags: c

```
    #define MAX 100
    typedef struct dado{
    int num[MAX];
    int qtd;
    }Dados;
    typedef struct {
    Dados dados;
    }Lista;
    typedef struct no{
    int numero;
    struct no *prox;

    }No

    typedef struct {
    No *cabeca;
    }LISTA
void insere(No *novo){

novo->prox=novo;


}
```

//Agora preciso que me ajudem a converter uma lista sequencial numa ligada sou consegui fazer as estruturas

Comment: Numa lista sequencial os dados estão organizados por contiguidade física numa lista ligada você tem que utilizar ponteiros para indicar aonde está o próximo dado.

Comment: Sei disso, mas não consigo fazer a conversão me ajude por favor

Answer (score 0):

A partir de sua pergunta entendi que o objetivo é a conversão de uma estrutura contendo dados sequenciais (um vetor e seu número de elementos) em uma estrutura de lista ligada (contendo cabeça).

Não compreendo a razão para o aninhamento de duas estruturas na lista sequencial, mas mesmo assim fiz o programa conforme os tipos que você definiu (apenas alterei o nome).

O código segue abaixo. Separei as funções de impressão e inseri comentários para ajudar no entendimento. O vetor foi inicializado com alguns dados de exemplo.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100


// tipo dos dados da lista sequencial
typedef struct dados {
    int num[MAX];
    int qtd;
} dados;

// tipo da lista sequencial
typedef struct {
    dados dados;
} lista_sequencial;

// tipo dos nós da lista ligada
typedef struct no {
    int numero;
    struct no *prox;
} no;

// tipo da cabeça da lista ligada
typedef struct lista {
    no *cabeca;
} lista_ligada;


// função para impressão da lista sequencial 
void imprime_lista_sequencial(lista_sequencial *ls) {
    for(int i = 0; i < ls->dados.qtd; i++)
        printf("%d ", ls->dados.num[i]);
}

// função para impressão da lista ligada
void imprime_lista_ligada(lista_ligada *ll) {
    no *p;
    p = ll->cabeca;
    while(p != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", p->numero);
        p = p->prox;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Inicializa lista sequencial */
    lista_sequencial ls;
    for (int i=0; i <= 20; i++) {
        ls.dados.num[i] = i * 2;
    }
    ls.dados.qtd   = 21;

    // impressão da lista sequencial
    printf("Lista Sequencial: ");
    imprime_lista_sequencial(&ls);

    // criação da lista ligada com cabeça e cópia dos dados da lista sequencial */
    lista_ligada ll;
    ll.cabeca = NULL;
    no **pn = &ll.cabeca;

    for (int i = 0; i < ls.dados.qtd; i++) {
        *pn = (no *) malloc(sizeof(no));
        (*pn)->numero = ls.dados.num[i];
        (*pn)->prox = NULL;
        pn = &(*pn)->prox;
    }

    // impressão da lista ligada 
    printf("\nLista Ligada: ");
    imprime_lista_ligada(&ll);
}
```

Comment: Olha muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas a ideia em pegar um Lista sequencial e depois converter ela numa lista simplesmente ligada.... Tentei juntar o teu código ao meu e após apresentar os valores do vector o ambiente está a fechar-se por si.

Comment: Estou com dificuldade de entender como funciona esta lista sequencial. Você já tem ela implementada?

Comment: Uma lista sequencial, é tipo de lista que os dados são armazenadas de forma sequencial, onde não existe um nó cabeça.

Comment: Exemplo de uma lista sequencial

Comment: #define MAX 30
typedef int tipo_dado;
//variavel global...
int i,j;

typedef struct{
 int qtd;
 int dados[MAX];
 
}Lista;

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//criar lista
int criaLista (Lista *li)
{
 li->qtd = 0;
}

Comment: Editei a resposta para o programa usar as estruturas exatamente como você descreveu. Veja se resolveu.